# Retrieve data into EditText from SQL Lite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently working on a small application which allows a persons details to be stored in a database and then retrieved into an EditText field. Currently i am able to store a persons name into the database. But i am having trouble retrieving this data.

Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
 package my.example.com.mymedicare;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "user.db", null, 4);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Users (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , FullName VARCHAR, Email VARCHAR, Number INTEGER, Age INTEGER, Nurse VARCHAR)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}
 }
```

SQLHelper.java:

```
 package my.example.com.mymedicare;

 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 public class SQLHelper  {
Context mContext;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
public SQLHelper(Context mContext) {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    this.mContext = mContext;
}



public boolean insert(String FullName, int i){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("FullName", FullName);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Register.java:

```
package my.example.com.mymedicare;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
};


public void btnCreate(View view) {

    SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(this);

    EditText addName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    sqlHelper.insert(addName.getText().toString(), 0);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Your Account Details Have Been Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainMenu.class));
}}
```

Modify.java:

```
 package my.example.com.mymedicare;

 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class Modify extends AppCompatActivity {

static SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify);

    EditText getName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameText);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Where is your code to do the query?

Comment: I have added the DatabaseHelper.java to the original post if that's what you mean? I am not too sure how to retrieve the FullName data and display it in the "nameText" EditText field.

Comment: There are several different commands you can use to get the data. Start here: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=android+sqlhelper+get+data

Comment: where is your get data from sqlite code ?

Comment: This is the issue i am having, i can store the name into the database in Register.java but unable to get the data into an edittext field in Modify.java.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step.

put this method in SQLHelper.java file.

```
    public ArrayList<String> fetch_Edittext() {
    ArrayList<String> arr_ = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_SCANITEMS + " ORDER BY id";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            arr_.add(cursor.getString(0));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return arr_;
}
```

put this class in your modify java class

```
private class GetEdittext extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // dialog start
        Log.e("Currency", "3");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<String> arr_ = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr_ = db.fetch_Edittext();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void resul) {
        super.onPostExecute(resul);
        // dialog dismiss
        //hear set your edit text
    }
}
```

then call this class at on create method like.

```
new GetEdittext().execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only errors i am getting now is "cannot resolve symbol" for TABLE_SCANITEMS  and "cannot resolve method" for getWritableDatabase

Comment: Edit: Fixed the getWritableDatabase error. Just not sure how to fix  "cannot resolve symbol" for TABLE_SCANITEMS

Comment: @ZenoX first uninstall your old apk file then this code set at DatabaseHelper.java class "db.execSQL(createtbl);" at oncreate method.

Comment: String selectQuery = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_SCANITEMS + " ORDER BY ID"; SQLite is case sensitive so change 'ID'.

Comment: @ZenoX insert value for this parameter "Email VARCHAR, Number INTEGER, Age INTEGER, Nurse VARCHAR"

Comment: The TABLE_SCANITEMS should be a constant defined on your helper, with the name of the table in the database, which is "Users" in your case. You can declare that constant on your helper class, or don't use it at all. Also you will need a reference to the EditText on your Modify activity inside the GetEdittask, you can use the class constructor to receive it.